# objective-C: Why isn't my loop terminating?

Tags: ios, objective-c, avfoundation

I am writing a swift application with an objective-C function to reverse an audio file. I am very new to Objective-C and I am specifically having trouble getting my loop to stop, even when my readPoint variable goes negative. How do I stop this loop when it hits zero?

```
#import "objectFile.h"
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <CoreAudio/CoreAudioTypes.h>

@implementation objectFile

-(void)callMethodFromObjectiveC{

NSURL *recordedAudioUrl;
NSURL *flippedAudioUrl;

NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
NSString *savedURL=[defaults objectForKey:@"savedURL"];

NSString *reverseURL=[defaults objectForKey:@"reverseURL"];

recordedAudioUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[savedURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
NSLog( @"url is %@", [recordedAudioUrl absoluteString]);

flippedAudioUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:[reverseURL stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

NSLog( @"url is %@", [flippedAudioUrl absoluteString]);

AudioFileID outputAudioFile;

AudioStreamBasicDescription myPCMFormat;
myPCMFormat.mSampleRate = 16000.00;
myPCMFormat.mFormatID = kAudioFormatLinearPCM ;
myPCMFormat.mFormatFlags =  kAudioFormatFlagsCanonical;
myPCMFormat.mChannelsPerFrame = 1;
myPCMFormat.mFramesPerPacket = 1;
myPCMFormat.mBitsPerChannel = 16;
myPCMFormat.mBytesPerPacket = 2;
myPCMFormat.mBytesPerFrame = 2;

AudioFileCreateWithURL((__bridge CFURLRef)flippedAudioUrl,
                       kAudioFormatMPEG4AAC,
                       &myPCMFormat,
                       kAudioFileFlags_EraseFile,
                       &outputAudioFile);
AudioFileID inputAudioFile;
OSStatus theErr = noErr;
UInt64 fileDataSize = 0;

AudioStreamBasicDescription theFileFormat;
UInt32 thePropertySize = sizeof(theFileFormat);

theErr = AudioFileOpenURL((__bridge CFURLRef)recordedAudioUrl, kAudioFileReadPermission, 0, &inputAudioFile);

thePropertySize = sizeof(fileDataSize);
theErr = AudioFileGetProperty(inputAudioFile, kAudioFilePropertyAudioDataByteCount, &thePropertySize, &fileDataSize);

UInt64 dataSize = fileDataSize;
void* theData = malloc(dataSize);

UInt64 readPoint  = dataSize;
UInt64 writePoint = 0;
while( readPoint > 0 )
{
    UInt32 bytesToRead = 2;
    AudioFileReadBytes( inputAudioFile, false, readPoint, &bytesToRead, theData );
    AudioFileWriteBytes( outputAudioFile, false, writePoint, &bytesToRead, theData );

    writePoint += 2;
    readPoint -= 2;
}

free(theData);
AudioFileClose(inputAudioFile);
AudioFileClose(outputAudioFile);

}
@end
```

Comment: put break; statement to break loop.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Where would I place the break; ?

Comment: @AvijitNagare 'while( readPoint > 0 )' is sufficient to cause the loop to end when 'readPoint -= 2" takes the value into negative, adding an 'if' statement would simply be introducing redundancy into the code. The exit condition does not need to be further checked. I would look at Gandalfs' answer below.

Comment: Though u have accepted my answer, i would suggest to look into the approach what @Kurt Revis has suggested. That way you don't loose the benefit of having more size to you variable.

Comment: Will do. Thank you very much for all the help Gandalf and @Kurt Revis! Now if I could only figure out why my audio file is not saving....looks like I have a lot more studying ahead of me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an unsigned int type variable and putting a check if it goes to negative values or not (readPoint > 0), which is not correct. You need a Signed Int to be able to make such comparison. Use this code

```
SInt64 readPoint  = dataSize;
```

Comment: If `readPoint` is going negative then it's reading more data than it should be.  Making it signed doesn't stop this issue.

Comment: @trojanfoe I think it would stop it as the condition will fail in case of Signed Int. I admit that i didn't took the big picture into account and just answered the part "why his loop was not breaking". That is why i have suggested him to look into Kurt Revis answer.

Answer (score 1):

Each time through the loop, you are requesting that `AudioFileReadBytes()` should read 2 bytes. It sets `bytesToRead` to the amount of data that it actually read.

Imagine that `readPoint` starts at 1. You ask for 2 bytes, but `AudioFileReadBytes` gives you only 1, because that's all that remains in the file. Then you decrement `readPoint` by 2, and since it's unsigned, it wraps around to a huge positive integer and your loop doesn't exit.

You should decrement `readPoint` by the amount that was actually read.

(You *don't* need to make `readPoint` a signed value. That just covers up the fact that you're doing the math wrong. If `AudioFileReadBytes` consistently returned less data than you asked for -- which it's allowed to do -- your math might end up off by more than just 1.)

```
UInt64 readPoint  = dataSize;
UInt64 writePoint = 0;
while( readPoint > 0 )
{
    UInt32 bytesToRead = 2;
    AudioFileReadBytes( inputAudioFile, false, readPoint, &bytesToRead, theData );
    // bytesToRead is now the amount of data actually read

    UInt32 bytesToWrite = bytesToRead;
    AudioFileWriteBytes( outputAudioFile, false, writePoint, &bytesToWrite, theData );
    // bytesToWrite is now the amount of data actually written
    // NOTE: You are assuming bytesToWrite == bytesToRead, which is not necessarily true.
    // You should ensure all the data is written before you read again.
    // I'm leaving that up to you.

    writePoint += bytesToWrite;
    readPoint -= bytesToRead;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Reason: Your conditional variable `readPoint` is an `unsigned` integer, which means it cannot have a negative value. The condition `readPoint > 0` will always be true and hence resulting in an infinite loop. You should be using simple `int`, `SInt64` or `NSInteger` in order to support negative values.

Comment: Since `UInt64 readPoint  = dataSize;` dataSize could be an odd value, that is what `readPoint` is never zero, and the loop continues.

Answer (score 0):

Using an unsigned type is fine in the loop, however you need to ensure that it does not go negative as that would mean it's reading more data than is available.

This is solved simply with:

```
UInt32 bytesToRead = MIN(readPoint, 2);
```

or:

```
while (readPoint >= 2)
```

depending on whether you want to allow odd-numbered sizes.